# AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Mappers:

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]

How can I fix my problem . I use mapper for Viewmodel between model .

I want to fix this exception .Only use mapper for between mapper and Viewmodel . Sure logic is correct. I want only Cleancode for my structure

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]. Your question severely lacks in details (the automapper set up and usage). Ideally provide a [mre].